# Variables defined in if-cases leak? (aka why does this even compile?)

Tags: c++

It seem that variables declared inside an if-statement leaks to the following statement?

I copy-pasted some code and to my surprise it compiled, when it shouldn't have!
I was about to commit the code and lucily I caught the error before that. Below here is a working (?) program that shows the problem.

The following code snippet calls a function on an object that doesn't exist:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
  void fooB() { std::cout << "fooB\n"; }
};

class C : public A {
public:
  void fooC() { std::cout << "fooC\n"; }
};

int main() {

   A* a = new C();

   if (B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a)) {
      b->fooB();
   } else if (C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(a)) {
      c->fooC();
      b->fooB();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

It compiles and the output is thus:

```
fooC
fooB
```

This is surely wrong. Do I need to enable some warning(s) to prevent this code from compiling?

Imagine the horrors if I tried to access some member variables or call a virtual function!

*Same behaviour both in VS2008 an GCC 4.8*

Comment: If and else if condition have assignment operator and not comparison operator ==, any reason for this??

Comment: @Nik: Yes. Common if you want to make sure the implicitly-tested-for-null variable doesn't escape outside the if-statement. I didn't think it'd be valid inside the `else` scope either

Comment: @Nik It's doing a `dynamic_cast`, which means that `B*` or `C*` have a possibility of returning `nullptr` if it can't cast. It's the equivalent of `if(!nullptr)` pretty much.

Comment: Did you mean `C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(a)`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes. Fixed.

Comment: I think to avoid such cases any assignments in If condition should not be done. We should get the required values before If condition and then check for there validity or any specific condition.

Comment: @Nik: The whole point of defining and assigning the variable inside the if-statement is to prevent null values from leaking out to the rest of the code. This is a quite common C++ idiom, recommended by Bjarne too, although apparently chaining if-else statements prevents this benefit slightly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does exist, but `b` is `NULL` on the `else` branch, and calling a function on it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok. defined variables are available in both branches, huh? Makes sense.

Comment: 6.4/3 A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the *type-specifier-seq* or the declarator of the condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements controlled by the condition. If the name is re-declared in the outermost block of a substatement controlled by the condition, the declaration that re-declares the name is ill-formed. [ Example: `if (int x = f()) { int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x } else { int x; // ill-formed, redeclaration of x }`